# Java client hangs on getResponseCode() when attempt to upload small size files

Tags: grails, file-upload

I have a client/server application with which the client is able to upload files to the server and then they are stored in a DB. I followed the instructions found in the  [following article](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/upload-file-to-servlet-without-using-html-form).

It works fine with files bigger than 1MB, but it doesn't with smallers: the client hangs on getResponseCode().

Here there is my specific client code:

```
final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://localhost:8080/myApp/myUploadAction"

// takes file path from first program's argument
String filePath = "/home/user/myCSV.csv"
File uploadFile = new File(filePath);

System.out.println("File to upload: " + filePath);

// creates a HTTP connection
URL url = new URL(UPLOAD_URL);
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");

// sets file name as a HTTP header
httpConn.setRequestProperty("fileName", uploadFile.getName());

// opens output stream of the HTTP connection for writing data
OutputStream outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream()

// Opens input stream of the file for reading data
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);

System.out.println("Start writing data...");

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead;

while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    println bytesRead
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}

System.out.println("Data was written.");

outputStream.close();
inputStream.close();

// always check HTTP response code from server
int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
// reads server's response
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        httpConn.getInputStream()));
String response = reader.readLine();
System.out.println("Server's response: " + response);
} else {
    System.out.println("Server returned non-OK code: " + responseCode);
}
```

Here there is my server side code. The server is based on a Grails application which exposes the following controller to the client:

```
class UploaderController {

    ReportService reportService

    def uploadCSV() {

        // get CSV file and NPL process name from HTTP header
        String fileName = request.getHeader("fileName");

        log.info('npl-getcolls-report: received request for ' + nplProcessName + ' - file uploading - ' + fileName)

        // prints out all header values (if debug mode is active)
        println("===== Begin headers =====")
        Enumeration<String> names = request.getHeaderNames()
        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = names.nextElement()
            println(headerName + " = " + request.getHeader(headerName))
        }
        println("===== End headers =====\n")

        // open input stream of the request for read incoming data
        InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream()

        // store CSV into DB
        reportService.storeCSV(fileName, inputStream.getBytes())

        log.info("data received and stored correctly in DB");

        inputStream.close();

        def responseData = [
                'status': 'OK'
        ]
        render responseData as JSON
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with the [apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html), rather than rolling your own post code? Example here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientChunkEncodedPost.java

Comment: Thank you tim_yates, using apache HttpClient now it works as expected!!

Comment: Completely unrelated - you shouldn't be creating a new instance of `ReportService` like that, assuming it's a Grails service under `grails-app/services`. Just use dependency-injection for the Spring-managed instance with `def reportService` or `ReportService reportService`

Comment: Definitely right, Burt. Edited, thanks